# Onclick keep calling function even after removing onclick from the element

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I am creating a simple rock paper scissors game.
when user choose a gesture (image) it has onclick to call function to generate a random gesture (bot).

**ISSUE:** i am using the seguent js code to remove all onclicks from all (3) gestures for 5 seconds but it does NOT work as expect.

```
    for(let i = 0; i < gestures.length; i++){
         gestures[i].onclick = null;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < gestures.length; i++){
        gestures[i].onclick = function(){
            Play(this);
        };
    }
}, 5000);
```

-this code is inside the Play() function-

relative html part:

```
                <div class="type">
                    <h2>Rock</h2>
                    <img class="gesture" src="rock.png" id="rock" alt="Rock" width="250px" height="250px" onclick="Play(this)">
                </div>
                <div class="type">
                    <h2>Paper</h2>
                    <div class="wrapper" >
                        <img class="gesture" src="paper.png" id="paper" alt="Paper" width="200px" height="200px" onclick="Play(this)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="type">
                    <h2>Scissors</h2>
                    <img class="gesture" src="scissors.png" id="scissors" alt="Scissors" width="250px" height="250px" onclick="Play(this)">
                </div>
```

Comment: What is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` instead?

Comment: @NickSlash the unexpected behaviour is that when i re-click the image the onclick is still there and call the js function 'Play(this)' before the 5 seconds ends. in other words how the onclick work if it has no onclick because i assigned onclcik to null

Comment: @5DimentionalObject yes i tried but somehow the onclicks in all the 3 gesture (images) is working even when i am setting it using "addEventListener" and "removeEventListener"

Comment: Ps: debug shows that the line (and all the code) is being excuted correctly

Comment: Not a solution to your issue but instead of removing the listeners you could add a check inside your listener and use the timeout to toggle the variable it checks?

Comment: @NickSlash accually that was the original code but it was not working as well. i think the issue is in the setTimeOut that somehow not working as it supposed

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @5DimentionalObject You can't use `removeEventListener` with an anonymous closure. The listener needs to be a named function so you can pass the same one to both `add` and `remove`.